# Best way to patch my local web applications

Tags: php, jquery

Hi can anyone please guide me on this. I have multiple raspberry pi with a local instance of php and each rpi contains a local web application. Now everytime i need to patch my code (php,html,jquery or css) i have to remotely connect to each rpi via teamviewer. But this becomes problematic since i have 100 rpi installed in different areas already and patching them with updated codes can be taxing if i need to use teamviewer.

Now i am willing to take a different approach... My plan is to tell the owners of the raspberry pi to go and click a link that will automatically download the files and if needed to overwrite existing files so that i dont need to connect to each rpi anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be using git and webhooks. You can then push your changes and have them automatically pulled onto each server. The downside being that you need to set up git on each server and configure a script to push to all servers which is quite a task.

Another option would be to use Ansible as you can push changes from a master raspberry pi to all the others. Again, setup is required, although you could set one up, put a setup script on github, for example, and have users run it. That way the next time you need to make changes; the users don't need to do anything.